# SQL Server filestream access from another computer using system account

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-cluster, filestream

I have a SQL Server 2008 set up to use filestream. SQL Server runs under a domain account with SPN set and delegation enabled.

Accessing filestream from another computer using a domain account works.

But accessing filestream from another computer using the other computer's localsystem account fails with an error 5 (access denied).

What might be the problem (apart from my lack of understanding)?

Both servers are running Windows Server 2003 on x86.

Update: Further testing showed that this appears to be a cluster problem. The physical node's shares can been seen from local system accounts, but the logical SQL node's cannot.

Update: Turns out the computer account for the SQL Network Name in the SQL cluster group was missing. It was created, but not the Network Name resource for the SQL Server doesn't start any more because it is (quoting eventvwr) "Unable to update password for computer account". Complete error message follows:

The computer account for Cluster resource 'SQL Network Name (thatname)' in domain ourdomain could not be created for the following reason: Unable to update password for computer account.

The text for the associated error code is: Access is denied.

The Cluster Service Account may lack the proper access rights to Active Directory. The domain administrator should be contacted to assist with resolving this issue.

End error message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is everything that is required, but after some research our Active Directory guy assigned to the cluster service account the right to change the local system account password of the logical computer used for the SQL cluster.

That seemed to do the trick!